# Distinguishing /f–t–θ/ in th-fronting and th-stopping dialects

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, homophones, phonemes

In standard English, the [digraph *th*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_of_English_%E2%9F%A8th%E2%9F%A9) is a dental fricative [θ, ð]. Several dialects feature [*th*-fronting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th-fronting), where *th* becomes a labiodental fricative [f, v]; others feature [*th*-stopping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th-stopping), where *th* becomes a dental stop [t̪, d̪]. For example, *three* sounds like *free* with *th*-fronting, *tree* with *th*-stopping.

How well can English speakers distinguish word pairs in these dialects? Specifically:

- Can *th*-modifying speakers distinguish /f–θ/ and /t–θ/ in their own dialects?
- Can they distinguish minimal pairs as spoken in standard English?
- Can standard English speakers distinguish the *th*-modified variants from similar words?

I expect that the answers vary between dialects and individuals, so I'm interested in reasonable generalizations. If there's a significant difference between (for example) *th*-fronting in Cockney and African American Vernacular English, I'd be interested in that too. Likewise if there's a significant difference between the voiced and unvoiced consonants.

Wikipedia notes that *th*-stopping dialects generally distinguish between the dental stop of *thanks* [t̪æŋks] and the alveolar stop of *tanks* [tæŋks], but they lose the /t–θ/ opposition in some cases like *tree/three,* and the /d–ð/ opposition is even weaker. This answers part of the question for *th*-stopping dialects: They can sometimes (but not not always) distinguish /t–θ/ in their own dialect, and I imagine they can also hear the opposition in standard English. I'm not sure whether a typical speaker of standard English could distinguish [t̪æŋks] from [tæŋks], however.

One case that particularly interests me is whether *th*-fronting speakers can distinguish the /f–θ/ opposition in standard English. When I say the minimal pair *free–three* /fɹi–θɹi/, can *th*-fronting speakers hear the difference, or is [f–θ] an allophone in free variation for them?

---

Examples of standard English minimal pairs that might merge in these dialects:

- *father/fava, mother/mutter*
- *thin/fin, thin/tin*
- *three/free, three/tree*
- *with/whiff, with/wit*
- *wraith/Ralph, wraith/rate*

Comment: I don't think this question requires a linguist's expertise to answer – indeed, I'm interested in the personal experience of _th_-modifying speakers – but I understand if this question is more appropriate for [linguistics.se].

Comment: _TH_ also represents the phoneme /ð/ as well as the phoneme /θ/. The voicing is not automatic or predictable, though the distinction has a very low functional load in English. Examples of /ð/ are lots more common in English than examples of /θ/, because /θ/ is used mostly in lexical words, while /ð/ is used mostly in function words like _the, this, that, either, other, although_ that we use thousands of times a day.

Comment: @John Yes, I'm also interested in the voiced consonants; I mostly glossed over them in the question because I felt that the explanation was complicated enough already!

Comment: [This](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/phono_atlas/Atlas_chapters/Ch08_2nd.rev.pdf) chapter from the U.Penn. *Atlas of NA English* suggests that merger in production is irregularly associated with distinction in perception. But I'd guess that on the ground perceptive distinction is always more dependent on semantic and syntactic than on phonetic contrast.

Comment: @StoneyB Very interesting reference! It looks like the association between production and perception is quite strong, but not absolute (which matches my personal experience). I do wonder how it applies to sounds that don't even appear in standard English (like stopped _th_) and sounds that are very distinct in standard English (like fronted _th_). But then I suppose that people who don't merge Mary–marry–merry see those vowels as very distinct too, when I can't hear a bit of difference.

Comment: @BraddSzonye Oh, yes. I come from a small southern college town, where there was substantial dialectal contrast, even discounting the 'foreigners' from north of the Mason-Dixon line, between those of us (mostly from University and top-caste town families) who distinguished those vowels and those of us (mostly from farm/proletarian families) who did not. The non-discriminators understood Mary/marry/merry and pin/pen perfectly well in discourse but insisted they sounded **exactly the same**, no matter who spoke them. You hear what you expect to hear.

Comment: @StoneyB Moving from Michigan to Northern California, I had a similar experience with the _cot-caught_ merger. The most shocking example was when I was introduced to a colleague named Don and expected to meet a woman (Dawn). I get the impression that locals can tell that there's something funny about the way I say half my Os, but they can't seem to tell the difference when I say _Don/Dawn_ either. So I'm very curious to know whether _th_-fronters have a similar difficulty with whiff. :)

Comment: Or [**yoots**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eNZ1O2KTOOg)?

Comment: @StoneyB A classic example of _th_-stopping! An interesting point: After researching this subject, I can actually hear the subtle difference between Pesci's dental “yoot(h)s” and Wynne's alveolar “yoots,” but before today I wouldn't have noticed the distinction. And clearly, Pesci _can_ say “yooothes,” with some difficulty (although it's hard to say whether the difficulty is genuine or acted).

Comment: An interesting similar shift is from wh- to w-. Many Americans, even those speaking so-called "Standard Englsh," now pronounce "which" like "witch," "where" like "ware," "whale" like "wail," and (my favorite) "whacky" like "wacky." (In fact, the last is now evem mostly spelled "wacky" and "whack" is spelled "wacK" as in "Wack-a-Mole.")

Comment: I would say I feel you can be in transition of a merger even within myself. Growing up between different english dialects, I often find that I can hear the difference , but that the choice of making the distinction is optional: similar as to how I can hear the difference between "whine / wine" and "hue / you" or even "do / dew" and "mayor / mare" when I hear them being distinguished, but its not necessary to do so, and distinguishing them is a choice made by the speaker

Comment: @WMBear _Wack_ and _whack_ are the same word historically speaking, and the derived adjectives _wacky_ and _whacky_ mean the same thing… so I'm not sure why that one is your favourite..?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think one can attempt to answer the question as is. By definition, if you merge, in production two sounds in your own dialect with respect to another (or rather rewrite one sound to an existing one), then two words that started in the standard dialect as different but are pronounced the same in the dialect are *by definition* indistinguishable (production or hearing) in that dialect. In some dialect, there is no distinction between 'three' and 'tree' there's just 'tree', spoken or heard, for the two different concepts. Only by definition, you cannot distinguish them if they merge.

Also, some rules are very context sensitive, those who say 'muvver' for 'mother' don't always say 'vin' for 'then' (oops, showing my pen/pin merger). So one may merge in certain contexts, but still produce and hear the unmerged context just fine.

Then, what truly is your question: are you talking about an individual speaking a dialect with a universal merge being able to distinguish them in another dialect where it is not merged? Then the answer, still by definition, is 'no', unless that person has enough exposure to the other dialect.